# Linq2sql queries on tab separated datafile

Tags: c#, linq, csv

How to use Linq2SQL Queries on Tab separated data sources?

I like to create a generic code base, where 2 tsv files can contain any # of columns, and once the linq query is passed to the program, it outputs the resultant data.

Answer (score 0):

You can't LINQ to SQL is for communicating with SQL server databases.  Maybe you mean LINQ generically, in which case I would direct you to: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library

This is technically for comma separated values, but modifying it to use TSV should be pretty straight forward.